How to derive the stress tensor in quantum mechanics?
Nielsen in his article Phys. Rev. B 35, 9308 (1987) derived the stress via a stretched particle coordinate $\mathbf{r}_{i\alpha}\rightarrow \mathbf{r}_{i\alpha}+\sum_\beta \epsilon_{\alpha\beta}\mathbf{r}_{i\beta}$ applied to the ground state $\Psi(\mathbf{r})$, where $i$ denotes to the particle index and $\alpha,\beta$ concern the dimension. The wave function becomes
$$
\Psi_\epsilon(\mathbf{r})=\det(\mathbb{1}+\epsilon)^{-1/2}\Psi((\mathbb 1 + \epsilon)^{-1}\mathbf{r}),
$$
where the prefactor is used for normalization. Then, he got the expectation of the Hamiltonian $H=\sum_i \mathbf{p}_i^2/2m_i + V$ by variable substitution $\mathbf{r}\rightarrow (1+\epsilon)\mathbf{r}$ as
$$
\langle \Psi_\epsilon| H |\Psi_\epsilon\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\,\Psi^*(\mathbf{r})\left\{ \sum_i\frac{1}{2m_i}\left[ \mathbf{p}_i^2 - 2\sum_{\alpha,\beta}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}p_{i\alpha}p_{i\beta} + \sum_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma}p_{i\beta}p_{i\gamma} \right] \\+ V((1+\epsilon)\mathbf{r}) \right\}\Psi(\mathbf{r}).
$$
The last step is to get the derivative with respect to $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}$. It's easy to do.
In the formula $\langle \Psi_\epsilon| H |\Psi_\epsilon\rangle$, the term of the potential is obvious, but I don't know how to get the kinetic terms $\left[ \mathbf{p}_i^2 - 2\sum_{\alpha,\beta}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}p_{i\alpha}p_{i\beta} + \sum_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\alpha\gamma}p_{i\beta}p_{i\gamma} \right]$. Any help is highly appreciated.

I think I got the way.
Writing the momentum operator in the coordinate representation, the key term is
$$
\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm d ((1+\epsilon)\mathbf{r})}\right)^2 = \left( (1+\epsilon)^{-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}\right)^2.
$$
Use the approximation $(1+\epsilon)^{-1}\approx 1 - \epsilon$, through matrix product is easy to get
$$
\left((1-\epsilon_{11})\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \epsilon_{12}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \epsilon_{13}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^2
+\left(-\epsilon_{21}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + (1 - \epsilon_{22})\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \epsilon_{33}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^2
+\left(-\epsilon_{31}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \epsilon_{32}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + (1 - \epsilon_{33})\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^2.
$$
That's the answer.
